# Реакция приложения за n минут до временной метки Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Доброго времени суток! Необходимо что бы приложение за некоторое константное время до заранее определенной временной метки вызывало событие или что-то в это роде. Описание немного сумбурное, приведу пример: за 5 минут до 12:00 по системным часам произвольный UI-элемент менял цвет. У меня, к сожалению, никаких идей нет на этот счет.

**UPD:** почему-то только сейчас пришло осознание, что подобный функционал похож по поведению на будильник, нашел кое-что: [How to: Create Alarms and Reminders for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(VS.92).aspx#BKMK_Background) и [Windows Phone Multitasking–Scheduled Notifications](http://blog.markarteaga.com/WindowsPhoneMultitaskingndashScheduledNotifications.aspx). Вечером приду домой попробую и отпишусь.

**UPD2:** по поводу первого *UPD*, не подходит вариант, потому что по истечению указанного периода выскакивает заранее определенное сообщение, ибо Scheduled Notifications - это сервис ядра.

Comment: Очень похоже на то. Но, как я понял при беглом просмотре, на каждый таймер только один callback. А мне нужно привязать реакцию к порядка 16 UI-элементам, что создавать 32 таймера с разными параметрами callback-а?. Это раз. И два... а что с производительностью? Не приходилось баловаться с этой штукой?
PS: пока не могу проверить.

Comment: На самом деле я вообще не имею никакого отношения к .Net, это когда-то давно читал книгу и отложилось в голове... 

Если я правильно понял принцип работы то проблем с производительностью быть не должно. Хоть и при 1000 таймерах.

В любом случае это лучше чем while в 32ух потоках или 32 "болванистых" потока со sleep'ами :D

****
речь идет о
[System.Threading.TimerCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx)

Comment: Создавать 32 таймера не имеет смысла, ну LOL-же, поместите в один обработчик сразу несколько вызовов ваших методов =)

Comment: Там фишка в том, что каждому таймеру *свои* параметры по периоду срабатывания. Но это на вскидку... вобщем надо попробовать.

Answer (score 1):

ну, навскидку либо использовать класс DateTime (проверку времени сам обдумай), либо, что, имхо, рациональнее, XNA класс GameTimer. При использовании DateTime будет сложно избежать поллинга (мб и несложно, но мне на ум ничего не приходит)

Answer (score -4):

```
        bool Done = false;
        bool i = false;

        while (i == false)
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now.Hour == 15) && (DateTime.Now.Minute == 19) && (Done == false))
            {
                Done = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Есть!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Боже, мои глаза.

Comment: А что такого, работает же??

Comment: @niki-timofe

Навскидку:

- Вы сожрали 100% процессорного времени.

- Как отработает этот код, если после 55 минуты юзер поменял настройки времени *(или у него сработала автосинхронизация)*?

- Что получится, если "действие в указанное время" выбросит эксепшн? Оставим `Done` в состоянии `true`?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что цикл с постоянным опросом - не решение. Я полагаю, имеются какие-нибудь средства, позволяющие Вызвать событие в определенное время.Тут пожалуй принцип будильника как-то повторить надо. Но как?

Comment: - Это я знаю, но ни чего более поверхностного, кроме как цикл, я не вижу
 - Не подумал, исправил XD
 - Try Catch, только я не знаю как в C# это реализуется...

Comment: А элемент Timer в C# для WP7 есть?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, это же индусское исполнение паттерна «торможение двигателем». Хотя надо отметить, что он меркнет по сравнению с подобной реализацией на SQL для хранимой процедуры Oracle в соседнем треде :-) Я минуснул, хотя бы потому, что не `while (true)` /* циклы не знаем? */

Comment: Циклы знаем, но не помним, как while реализуется на C#

Comment: **Весело у вас тут.**

Comment: Есть же Thread.Sleep который может дрыхнуть до назначенного времени (или иногда вставать и проверять не сменилось ли системное время)

Comment: @karmadro4 Там тоже нетривиально - `Thread.Sleep(X)` [**не точен**][1] и зависит от процессов, происходящих в системе.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303667/how-accurate-is-thread-sleeptimespan

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, не уверен, что для UI нужна миллисекундная точноть...

Comment: Сильный ответ. Учитывая, что вопрос про телефон, для достаточно больших интервалов работать не будет, т.к. **в реальном мире сядет батарейка**.

Comment: `while (false == false)` и `if(... && false == false)` лучший способ использования логических операций!

Comment: Да оставте уже эту ветку. Ясно, что совет ни о чем. Просто niki-timofe немного молод и в .NET не силен, не говоря уже о WP7 платформе.

Comment: @avp, а что телефон? При таком подходе может сесть даже Братская ГЭС.