# Как на Windows Phone сделать фоновое задание, повторяющееся каждый час в 0 минут?

Tags: c#, background-task, windows-phone-7, visual-basic

Как на Windows Phone сделать фоновое задание, повторяющееся каждый час в 0 минут?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точностью до секунд или минут это невозможно.

В остальных случаях, можно использовать [**`PeriodicTask`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask(v=vs.92).aspx)

Comment: А кто минусует, может быть, даст правильный ответ? Лично мне кажется что нельзя, вопрос задан 17 дек. и до сих пор никто не ответил, а в Windows Phone API я нашёл только функцию для создания будильника и напоминания....

Comment: Ммм, я не минусовал, но логика наверное такая: в ответе нет собственно ответа на вопрос. "С точностью до секунд или минут это невозможно." подразумевает, что это возможно, но как именно не написано.

Comment: Хм...

Вопрос мой, ответ тоже, и за ответ, который меня *устраивает* мне ещё и минусуют...

Comment: Суровая реальность социума: помоги себе сам, да еще и будь покаран за это =)

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Как уже указали выше, есть `PeriodicTask`, он запускается операционной системой раз в полчаса (и то это не гарантируется). Теоретически вы можете в нем проверять и работать каждый второй раз (получается раз в час), но опять же нет никакой гарантии, что это будет ровно раз в час и ровно в 0 минут.

Answer (score 0):

Подобный вопрос интересовал в свое время. Но немного в другом контексте. Если интересно, [почитай ветку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/109222/c-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0-n-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-windows-phone-7), может найдешь для себя решение. Я для себя особо путного не нашел, посему отказался от этой фичи в приложении.